# How can I remove a css portion when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to remove this css portion from a navbar-collapse when I click a button:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function()
{
   $(".navbar-collapse").remove("ul.nav","li.dropdown","ul.dropdown-menu");
});
```

But it doesn't work.  I want to have a responsive navbar menu and when it collapse remove the dropdowns from that view.

Comment: You want to remove the classes or the CSS?

Comment: Why do you need to remove display block?  Are you trying to hide those elements? If so you can just use .hide()

Comment: You can't really remove the css portion, well, you can, but that's probably not what you want, you want to either remove the classes, or apply new styles that override the old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to just set css attribute `display` to `none` on class `.dropdown-menu` applied to `ul` element.

`ul.nav li.dropdown:hover` doesn't have any relevancy here since they are used as an element locator and does not have `display:none` applied to them.

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function()
{
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').css('display','none');
});
```

To remove the entire css attributes,

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function()
{
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removeClass?

```
$(".navbar-collapse").removeClass("nav dropdown dropdown-menu");
```

If you want to remove the elements from the DOM

```
$(".nav, .dropdown, .dropdown-menu").remove();
```

Comment: When I resize the windows I made a bootstrap menu responsive with a button.  I want to hide the dropdowns when I display that menu, but keeping the attributes when the full sreen is back.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than one way to accomplish this but you can do it by changing the css when you click the button

Here's how you would accomplish that:

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function()
{
   $("ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu").css({"display": "none"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#toggleButton").click(function(){
   $(".navbar-collapse").remove("ul.nav li.dropdown > ul.dropdown-menu");
});
```